# Showing tracks based on album art

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I need help with figuring out a way to make the tracks in my database show only to the respective album art.

My database table is as follows

```
album_art
——————-
ID (int, primary)
Name (Varchar(200))
Image (long text)
a_correlation (varchar(200))
Type (varchar(50))
Info (text)
——————-

tracks
——————-
tID (int, primary)
tName (varchar(200))
tLocation (long text)
t_correlation (varchar(200))
time (time stamp)
——————-
```

Those are the two tables.

I had the below query on my site but it displayed every single track in the database under each album art

```
$query = “SELECT * FROM tracks, album_art WHERE album_art.a_correlation = tracks.t_correlation”
```

Please tell me how If it’s the query that might have the problem, or how you suggest I go about it. I just want each track to be under their respective album art. If you need additional information please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't testing for any specific album art

Comment: What do you mean? I’m trying to figure out how to display a track with its own artwork but all the tracks show up on each and every artwork

Comment: If you want the artwork for a specific track then you need to specify the track name in the where condition, if you want to get all the tracks for an artwork you need to specify the artwork in the where condition. You should also lose the implicit join in favour of an explicit join.

Comment: I thought I did specify that I wanted all the tracks for an artwork. How would I do that then?